# Why can't I push data on the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Can you tell me why this code produces error?
I want to create a multidimensional array

```js
const segments = ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'];
console.log(segments)
let cols = [];
let currSegment, currLetter;

for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i += 1) cols.push([]);

console.log(cols[2])
//cols.push([])
console.log(cols.length + ' :L')

for (let j = 0; j < segments.length; j += 1) {
  currSegment = segments[j];
  for (let k = 0; k < currSegment.length; k += 1) {
    currLetter = currSegment[k]
    cols[k].push(currLetter);

  }
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: So, what should the output be? It looks like it should be `[['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'], ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'], ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd']]`, is that right?

Comment: Apparently the value of `cols[k]` is not an array because that element is `undefined`.

Comment: I assume that what you meant to do is `cols[j].push(currentLetter);`

Comment: You probably meant `cols[j]` instead of `cols[k]`

Comment: sidenote: your entire code can be reduced to `const cols = segments.map(item => item.split(""));`

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing with wrong index, corrected the code.

```js
const segments = ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'];
console.log(segments)
let cols = [];
let currSegment, currLetter;

for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i += 1) cols.push([]);

console.log(cols[2])
//cols.push([])
console.log(cols.length + ' :L')

for (let j = 0; j < segments.length; j += 1) {
  currSegment = segments[j];
  for (let k = 0; k < currSegment.length; k += 1) {
    currLetter = currSegment[k]
    cols[j].push(currLetter);

  }
}

console.log(cols)
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand my logical error. I was wondering if I could use index j or k.

Answer (score 0):

With the value of `k` after third iteration, you are trying to push an item in an *index* which does not really exist.

Change

```
cols[k].push(currLetter);
```

To

```
cols[j].push(currLetter);
```

```js
const segments = ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'];
console.log(segments)
let cols = [];
let currSegment, currLetter;

for ( let i = 0; i < segments.length; i += 1 ) cols.push([]);

console.log(cols[2])
//cols.push([])
console.log(cols.length + ' :L')

for ( let j = 0; j < segments.length; j += 1 ) {
  currSegment = segments[j];
  for (let k = 0; k < currSegment.length; k += 1 ) {
    currLetter = currSegment[k]
    cols[j].push(currLetter);
  }
}
console.log(cols);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have pushed an empty array to the col only variable 2 times. You are trying to access cols[k] which is from 0 through 7 (if we considered the first index in the segments array).

Answer (score 0):

`cols[k]` doesn't exist - use `cols[j]`:

```js
const segments = ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'];
let cols = [];
let currSegment, currLetter;

for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i += 1) cols.push([]);

for (let j = 0; j < segments.length; j += 1) {
  currSegment = segments[j];
  for (let k = 0; k < currSegment.length; k += 1) {
    currLetter = currSegment[k]
    cols[j].push(currLetter);

  }
}

console.log(cols);
```

You can also optimize and make your code much more concise like so:

```js
const segments = ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'];
const cols = segments.map(e => [...e]);

console.log(cols);
```

The above is a lot faster - it has `O(N)` complexity because you're looping through `segments` once.

Answer (score 0):

`cols` contains only 3 empty arrays and at some point `k` will be greater than 2 so `cols[k]` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not concerned about your expected result, just pointing out the error in your code.
Take a look at your inner for loop:

```
for (let k = 0; k < currSegment.length; k += 1) {
        currLetter = currSegment[k]
        cols[k].push(currLetter);

    }
```

The loop runs on letter 'avgekcr', which has length 7, and length of *cols* array is just 3. Hence, cols[3] is undefined so it will simply throwing error:

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following way to add elements to "cols" because "cols" is one dimensional array. You can use cols[k].push only if that is a multi dimensional array.

```
cols.push(currSegment[k]);   // no need to define an additional variable to keep currSegment[k] value
```

And for your implementation simply you can use the split function to make string to a char array and concat function merge the previous cols and new char array.

```
const segments = ['avgekcr', 'efgghe', 'ewlskffd'];
let cols = [];

for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    cols = cols.concat(segments[i].split(''));
}
```

Use the following way if you need to access all segments in a 2-dimensional array.

```
for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    cols.push([]);
    cols[i] = segments[i].split('');
}
```

Comment: this is basically `let cols = segments.join("").split("");` and btw. his code creates a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: yes @Thomus for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i += 1) cols.push([]); make cols 2-dimensional. mm...thanks he is trying to access all characters in segments from a 2-dimensional array.